# SpriteKit Unwrap

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, ios10

I am trying to unwrap the speed value of an action to increase it every ten taps, but it doesn't change when I use '?' before the ".speed". If I use '!' it throws an "unwrapping an Optional value" error". How can I fix this issue?
Here's my code

```
 for child in self.children as! [SKSpriteNode] {
        if let block: SKSpriteNode = child as? SKSpriteNode {
            if (tapCount == 10) {
                block.action(forKey: "seq")?.speed += 0.5
                block.action(forKey: "seq2")?.speed += 0.5
                print(block.action(forKey: "seq2")?.speed)
                tapCount = 0
                print("YES")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: that first  `if` is unnecessary,  because your child is already SKSpriteNode (you should have a warning)  However I would advice against doing your for loop the way you are doing it, because once a non SKSpriteNode gets placed into children, your as! cast will fail

Comment: They will always be SKSpriteNode's so it should be okay to use !. I do agree that the first if is unnecessary though. It was originally used to cast to a subclass of SKSpriteNode, but is useless now. Thanks!

Comment: Just saying it is not good practice,  6 months down the road you may change your mind,  add an SKLabelNode, and bam. You are back on SO because you can't figure out why it is breaking and it is so easy to over look. Also. ! Is not the problem,  casting to SKSpriteNode is the problem.  I say leave the if, remove the cast

Comment: The cast in the for loop?

Comment: yes,  then your if check if child is sprite protects you

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When Swift throws a runtime error and complains about finding nil when unwrapping an Optional value, it means that your code assume some Optional value to be non-nil, when it is nil.

In a really small nutshell:

- The `?` means: try unwrapping and if it fails, don't continue.
- The `!` means: unwrap because I guarantee it's not `nil`.

To answer your question: I assume `block.action(forKey: "seq2")` returns nil. The action of which you want to alter the speed does not exist.

**Note**
If the `?` and `!` operators sound confusing to you, I'd recommend reading through Apple's [Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html) document. It is very useful to gain a good understanding of the tools Swift gives you to deal with potentially missing values.